# Fonts can't be used in apps with double click install

Tags: font, font-book

I am unable to use fonts in my apps until I restart or quit fontd from Activity Monitor. This problem only applies if I install the font by double clicking on the font file, however. If I go into Font Book first, the install works fine. It isn't that much of an issue, but I would appreciate the help to make it a little more convenient.

Comment: I find some apps need to be quit and relaunched, as they cache the OS font data. Other apps, like Affinity suite,  will do a live update.